# sql query to linq-to-entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

How can this query be transform to linq

```
SELECT materialId, SUM(totalAmount) as quantity FROM Inventory
```

It's the sum part that I don't know how...

```
  query = from inv in context.Inventory
                        select new MaterialQuantity() 
                        {
                            MaterialId = inv.materialId,
                            Quantity = ??
                        };
```

EDIT 
Trying to sum the value of totalAmount.

It's a view that is

```
materialId totalSum and other fields
1          5
1          10
1          20
```

So I want my linq to return me
MaterialId = 1, Quantity = 35

Comment: What are you trying to sum? Obviously there can be multiple materialId values, but unless you're grouping by something there'd only be a single sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give a complete guess here... assuming your inventory has multiple rows with the same materialId and you want to sum in those groups, you could use:

```
var query = from inv in content.Inventory
            group inv.totalAmount by inv.materialId into g
            select new { MaterialId = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum() };
```

If you're *not* trying to group though, you'll need to clarify your question. Sample data and expected output would help.